# Asking a question about an answer to another question

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm not sure the accepted answer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15107/changing-unix-group-for-files) is correct, and I have left a comment on it seeking further clarification from the author of the accepted answer (or voters).

Unfortunately the authors of the original question and accepted answer have not been online for a long time, and the question has been  "dead" for a long time.

My question is: Can I ask a question that seeks to clarify the answer to another question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go for it. It helps if you link to the original question and specifically mention how it's different, so yours doesn't get closed as a duplicate. For example:

> In [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15107/changing-unix-group-for-files/15109#15109) that moonshadow recommended setting the sticky bit on a directory to force files to keep the directory's group ID. Is that accurate? Wikipedia seems to indicate that he's actually referring to the setgid bit:
>
> > Setting the setgid permission on a directory (chmod g+s) causes new files and subdirectories created within it to inherit its group ID, rather than the primary group ID of the user who created the file.
>
> As far as I know, activating the sticky bit on the directory will only make sure that only the directories' files' owner, the directory's owner or root can modify the directories' files. Do I understand the distinction correctly?